# Scrapping some data from a football website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a Python program that extracts some data using Selenium where first I have to close two alerts then click on "Show all matches" button and finally I need to click on each "stats" button (there are multiple and they all have the same class name) to extract a specific row from this table.

[image: the stats buttons]

I need to extract the 4 values highlighted in blue for each game

[image: the table that I need to extract data from]

I already did the first two steps but now I'm stuck in the final one where I have to click on each "stats" button, extract the 4 values from each table then close the window and move to the next game.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

s=Service("C:/Users/dhias/OneDrive/Bureau/stgg/chromedriver.exe")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=1#")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[mode='primary']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"steady-floating-button"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Show all matches']"))).click()
```

and I tried this to click on every "stats" button that have the same class name but it didn't work

```
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='myButton' and text()='stats']"):
    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='myButton' and text()='stats']"))).click()
```

link to the website : [soccerstats website](https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=1#)

Comment: save links to array and navigate to it, after you have all link you can click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save links to array and click after because after click you are not on the page that have the links anymore

```py
stat_links = []
#get all urls
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='myButton' and text()='stats']"):
    stat_links.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
    
for link in stat_links:
    driver.get(link)
    # do your stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

You sure you need to be using Selenium here? You can easily pull those tables with pandas and requests.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=1#'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', text='stats')

filtered_links = []
for link in links:
    if 'pmatch' in link['href']:
        filtered_links.append(link['href'])

tables = {}
for count, link in enumerate(filtered_links, start=1):
    try:
        html = requests.get('https://www.soccerstats.com/' + link, headers=headers).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        
        goalsTable = soup.find('h2', text='Goal statistics')
        
        teams = goalsTable.find_next('table')
        teamsStr = teams.find_all('td')[0].text + ' ' + teams.find_all('td')[-1].text
        
        goalsTable = teams.find_next('table')
        df = pd.read_html(str(goalsTable))[0]
        
        print(f'{count} of {len(filtered_links)}: {teamsStr}')
        tables[teamsStr] = df
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(f'{count} of {len(filtered_links)}: {teamsStr} !! NO GOALS STATISTICS !!')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: All I got is "!! NO GOALS STATISTICS !!" for every game + I only need to scrape one specific row not the entire table

Comment: may need to add user agent

Comment: updated the code. give it a try